# 2d array rows/columns length C

Tags: c, arrays

I need to declare a 2d array to represent the size of chess-board. However, I'm having a trouble understanding how would I actually calculate the width and the length of the board. 
I would like to know how could I calculate size of the rows and columns of my 2d array

Say, `int boardSize[5][5]`?

```
int main()
{
   int boardSize[5][5];
   int boardWidth=?
   int boardHeight =?
   createBoard(boardWidth, boardHeight);
}

 int createBoard(int width, int height)
 {
   // code that actually creates board //
 }
```

Sorry, for not being specific in the begging. So, here I need to calculate boardwidth and boardheight variables? How do I do that from the declared array above. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Jack, welcome to stackoverflow. Right now it's unclear what is being asked here, can you be more precise? A small code example of what you're trying to achieve would be perfect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`boardSize[0]` gives you the first row of the matrix, `boardSize[0][0]` the first of its elements. So the quantities you are looking for are `sizeof boardSize/ sizeof boardSize[0]` and `sizeof boardSize[0]/ sizeof boardSize[0][0]`.

BTW: use `size_t` as a type for sizes, not `int`.

Comment: @larkey, why would that be? The base type is `int` here. So this would typically be `4`.

Comment: >.< Yeah, I came across it when working with chars for too long.

Answer (score 0):

If you say

```
int boardSize[5][5];
```

that gives you a 2D array of integers, 5 by 5 in size. So it will have 5 rows of 5 columns each, for a total of 25 integers.

Comment: I know that, I mean how would I pass these parameters as width and height to a function? I need to have a separate variables, say int width, int height.

Comment: @JackMorton - What you say in this comment was not at all clear from the question. I would suggest an edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Size of the board in bytes %d\n", sizeof(boardSize));
printf("Size of column size in bytes %d\n", 5*sizeof(int));
printf("Size of row in bytes %d\n", 5*sizeof(int));
```

If you want leave the board as statically allocated the declare it as global like,

```
static int board[5][5];
```

Then traverse it in your "createBoard" method(I hate Hungarian notations) for correct initialization :

```
for(i = 0; i < hight; i++)
  for(j = 0;j< width; j++)
     board[i][j] = <initialization stuff>
```

or you can dynamically allocate it in your createBoard() method. In that case do not declare as local variable for main.

```
int * createBoard(int hight, int width){
   int * board;
   if(board = malloc(sizeof(int) * hight * width))
       return board;
   return NULL;
}
```

in main() you can do something like this:

```
 int * board = createBoard(5,5);
 if(!board)
     printf("Allocation failure \n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily fixed with the removal of all mysterious magic numbers from your code.

```
#define BOARD_WIDTH  8
#define BOARD_HEIGHT 8


square_t board [BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];

createBoard (board, BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);


void createBoard (square_t* board, int boardWidth, int boardHeight)
{

}
```