# Arduino 2D Array Length (count of elements)

Tags: arduino

I have this array:

```
   int rainbowArray[][3] = {{255,0,0},{255,127,0},{255,255,0},{0,255,0},{0,0,255},{75,0,130},{148,0,211}};
```

How can i do count elements?

Comment: You mean how many integers? Or how many triplets of integers?

Comment: how many triplets of integers

Comment: @StoryTeller: Please don't change the question. OP explicxitly asked about Arduino!

Comment: @Olaf - I didn't change the question. The content presents a C array definition. The fact it's compiled to arduino's instruction set doesn't change it being C.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Arduino is **not** C. It is based on C++, but not exactly C++ either. You changed the language. (the fact your answer is the same does not change this fact. Please refrain from changing correct language tags. To cite your profile: "The vital importance of being precise."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2d array rows/columns length C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330124/2d-array-rows-columns-length-c)

Comment: @StoryTeller: C and C++ are distinct languages. A language **based** on C++ is not related to C! The C tag is unjustified, "Arduino" is a language of it's own". Tags are not to attract a maximim audience for your answer, but to correctly search and filter questions. And mind your language.

Comment: @Olaf - Arduino is not a language, for the love of god! The mistagging is done by you. And if you find "crusade" offensive, well tough luck, review your actions.

Comment: @Olaf - And don't you dare accuse me of tagging fraud. I've done my fair share of separating tags on questions I've answered.

Comment: @StoryTeller: A bit of reading would help. Arduino uses its own variant of the C++. So yes, in some way it can be seen as its own language. For the tomatotaste of his spaghettiness!

Comment: I told you are running into the wrong direction here. It actually surprised me you changed to tag for this question. Nevertheless it was not me accusing someone. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Olaf - No, you flat out accused me of tag fraud. The discussion of whether this is C or not has nothing to do with the accusation, which is both vile an untrue. *"Tags are not to attract a maximim audience for your answer"* - not accusing me of anything, right..

Answer (score 2):

A two dimensional array is just an "array of arrays". So the usual trick works:

```
sizeof rainbowArray / sizeof rainbowArray[0]
```

The above will produce a constant expression of type `size_t` that equals the number of "triplets".

Note however, that you can't apply this to pointers, only to variables of array type.